# Launch Screenflow from Custom button on Home Page

Tags: screen-flow

Is there anyway to launch the screenflow from button on Home Page(lightning experience). We can directly add the flows on Home Page but our requirement is launch from a button which opens new window for that.

How can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your flow in either a lightning component or a visualforce page and use the same in global action. Add this global action on the Global Publisher Layout. The resulting flow will open in a popup.

[image]

**FlowComp.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
  <aura:handler name = "init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}" />
  <lightning:flow aura:id="Quick Account" />
</aura:component>
```

**FlowCompController.js**

```
({
   doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
     var flow = component.find("Quick Account");
     flow.startFlow("Quick_Account");
   }
})
```

[Embed a Flow in a Custom Aura Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm)

[Embed Flows in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_adding.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! .But is there any way like we can add it as Quick action on Home page instead of global action ?

Comment: We can generally create Actions using lightning components and then we can add them on the page layouts for normal objects (that action should be visible in lightning).Same way, can we do that for Home Page and add that in the Home page Layout (that action should be visible in lighitning)

Comment: Any lightning component which implements `flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes` can be dragged and dropped from the Lightning App Builder to the Home Page layout. This, however, will not open the component in a popup. If you want to open a component in a popup, try creating a parent component with just a `lightning:button`. On click of the button, write the logic to open your component as a modal popup. Add the parent component on the Home Page layout.

Comment: Can you provide me sample code if possible

Comment: You can check out these posts on modal popups: https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/15/modal-box-lightning-component-salesforce/ https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/modal-popup-lightning-component-salesforce/